# Best way to to create a complex search form in Android

Tags: android, menu

I'm trying to create and Android application which requires a number of search criteria which will eventually form an SQL query and run against a database.

The first set of criteria I'd like to present as a 3-tier list where the choices are dependent on the prior choice but there is only one final choice. So you could navigate to commadore via Car > Holden > Commadore. But you may only want to navigate to Car (and see a list of all cars) or Holden and see a list of all holdens.

- Car

  - Holden

    - Commadore
    - Berina
  - Renault

    - Megan
- van

  - van 1

    - Van 1 type 1
    - Van 1 type 2

etc
etc

There will also be other criteria such as colour, place and a free text search, I'd like to  present these on a different tab or separate them somehow. I've looked at a tabbed layout but it appears that each tab uses a different activity and I believe that it is complicated for separate activities to talk to each other.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this as I don't have time to discover all the shortfalls with this that others may have already experienced. Thanks for your help.

Much appreciated.
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Views instead of activities for the content of each Tab. The Activity which contains your TabHost will then be able to use the values selected from each of the views.

As for the lists, and sublists you can start to look in to the [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), however that only provides a two level list, so you would need to look at extending it to allow n-levels I guess.

Alternatively you can have n-number of ListViews and transition between them IF the user makes a selection.

Comment: Hi C0deAttack, Thanks for your answer. Sorry that my initial description was a little unclear. If you imagine that a person may want to search for all cars then they would only access the menu to the point of Car (instead of van). however if they wished to be a little more specific then they could drill down to Holden and more specific still drill down to the model of the car under that. The results will be different depending on how much information the user chooses to give the application.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm really new to this so could you please explain a bit more around the transitions between the list views. Thanks mAndroid

Comment: This is the app I'm working on at the moment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nKhgpq3rQA Ignore the back button issue and just take a look at the transitions between the my List Views. You can create your own animations like fades, slides, scales from different directions, speeds etc. More here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html You can add those animations when you want to show a view. If you have questions about that better to create a new StackOverflow post for it. Good luck.